# JSLink, can it run when a choice dropdown changes?

Tags: javascript, jslink, edit-form

I have an EditForm that I am using JSLink to run some javascript that gets the Content Type and then sets a field according to the Content Type.

This works fine when the form loads, the trouble is when the user changes the Content Type the javascript does not run. Is there a way to get the javascript to run when the Content Type dropdown is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the custom template is registered after the `clienttemplates.js` library is loaded.

The following example prints into console:

```
PreRender event is triggered
PostRender event is triggered
```

when the edit form is loaded and once content type is changed (`ContentTypeChoice` control)

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

      OnPreRender: function(ctx) {
          console.log('PreRender event is triggered');
      },


      OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
         console.log('PostRender event is triggered');
      }

    });

});
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that, when you change a value in the Content Type dropdown, the form is submitted and loaded again, so your CSR code should work.

On the other hand, you can try to use JQuery and bind you functions to the `change()` [event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) on the HTML select element. You can select Content Type dropdown using `$('select[id$="_ContentTypeChoice"]` selector.

Comment: Thanks, yes I thought the page gets resubmitted on the dropdown change but unfortunately the code does not run. I haven't used JQuery before, would I need to put a CEWP on the page to get this to work?

Comment: You can add JQuery the same way you are adding JSLink. For example, in the edit form properties with `|` as separator. But if you code does not works after the resubmission maybe your function runs two early. Look at the @vadim answer and call your code in the `PostRender` event.